# To fit images file to an autokeras image classifier

Tags: python, auto-keras

I am trying to fit images file to an autokeras image classifier. Code I am using is given below,

```
import autokeras as ak
import os
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
path= '/Users/Downloads/business_cards/Canon/'
X_data = os.listdir(path)
training, test = train_test_split(X_data, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)
x= np.array([training])
print(x.shape)
clf = ak.ImageClassifier(overwrite=True, max_trials=1)
clf.fit(x,epochs=1)
```

But it gives me the following error,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Could someone please help me with this.

Comment: Could you please specify the line where you got the error?

Comment: seems like your not loading the data in properly? try to follow the documentation here: https://autokeras.com/tutorial/image_classification/

Comment: You have a problem with the variable `X if I'm correct , so `np.array([training])` give Null value , try to see the output of `print(training)`

Comment: @ abdou_dev, thank you for replying but training is my list of images that is in the following format:['094.jpg', '021.jpg','089.jpg','065.jpg'.........] and I am trying to fit this data to my classifier.

Comment: @abdou_dev, clf.fit(x, epochs =1) gives the error.

Comment: Your error is in `x.shape` , because x is null , please try to `print(np.array([training]))` and see the output

Comment: @abdou_dev, No, x.shape does not give null value it gives (1,80) value. My 'x' is ndarray of images, [['094.jpg','021.jpg'......]], even after I remove the brackets and give np.array(training), I still get the same error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.